# 2000 Toyota Camry, check engine light at 164,450 - what does this mean?

Tags: toyota, cel, camry

I purchased this car used just one year ago, and the check-engine light just came on yesterday. I'm not used to having a Toyota, or even a car - all my previous vehicles, for the past 15 years, have been big pickup trucks and SUVs.

So please - someone - can you give me an idea of what it wants me to do? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the world of OBD2. You need to have your vehicle scanned for codes and checked out accordingly.